# Binding Dropdown list which is inside footer of gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view with 3 columns(Product, Quantity, Price) with header and footer. I added a dropdownlist for the Product footer. Now I want to bind this dropdownlist with products which is in dataset, can anyone help me?
 i used the following code in cs file, but im getting error near find control as

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
protected void gv_page2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        dal = new DAL();
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds=dal.DALBindFooterDDL();
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)gv_page2.FooterRow.FindControl("ftrDDL");
            ddl.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddl.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should use gridview RowDataBound Event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RowCreated` (or `RowDataBound` event) - for example

```
void ProductsGridView_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.FooterRow)
    {
      // Find the product drop-down list, you can id (or cell number)
      var ddlProducts = e.Row.FindControl("Products") as DropDownList;
      // var ddlProducts = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0]; // Finding by cell number and index
      if (null != ddlProducts)
      {
          // bind to the data
      }
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: untested code - provided to get an idea/hint of actual soltion*

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void gv_page2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        dal = new DAL();
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds=dal.DALBindFooterDDL();
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("ftrDDL") as DropDownList;
            ddl.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddl.DataBind();
        }
    }
```